# python list slicing and moving around

Tags: python, list, slice

How can i make a list and slice it whenever a 27 or 28 appear and when its a 27 all the number after it would go to the top and any number before 28 would go bottom. And previously I only have a few function which involves swapping it but i'm not sure if it would help for this function.

```
>>> list = [1,2,3,28,4,5,6,27,7,8,9]
>>> list = [7,8,9,28, 4,5,6,27,1,2,3]


def triple_cut(cards):
    if 27 and 28 in cards:
        return cards[(index(27)):end] + cards[(index(28)):(index(27))] + cards[:(index(28))]
```

The logic should be like this but i cant do index for some reason can anyone help fix my code so it would work

Answer (score 0):

Use `cards.index(27)` and `cards.index(28)`

Comment: `return cards[cards.index(27)+1:] + cards[cards.index(28):cards.index(27)+1] + cards[:cards.index(28)]`

Comment: I tried it but apparently it gives me 
[27, 7, 8, 9, 28, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3] which instead i wanted ([7,8,9,28, 4,5,6,27,1,2,3])

Comment: So you almost get good result - you need only add `+1` in some places. See my previous comment.

Comment: what if i want to change the code after i already have a move_27 and move_28 which swaps 27 with the next number and 28 to the next 2 number
which should look like cards =  ([7,8,9,4,5,28,6,1,27,2,3])

Comment: new problem = create new question on stackoverflow.

Comment: I already posted this so i need to wait like 60 more minute could you answer it here?